# Какое слово используют русские математики для логического следования?

Tags: математика

Мой русский очень плохого качества. Пожалуйста, вернитесь к результатам поиска, если вы хотите читать только качественные вопросы и просто не отвечаете на вопросы, которые вам не нравятся.

Для тех, кто хочет участвовать здесь, не стесняйтесь нажимать кнопку редактирования и вносить улучшения.

---

Какое слово используют русские математики для логического следования?

---

Надеюсь, вы сможете использовать примеры, чтобы понять, что мы здесь пытаемся понять.

Примеры логических следствий показаны ниже.

## Определение *натуральной строки*

Мы определяем естественную строку как слово, фразу, предложение, абзац или текст любой длины.

| слово | фраза | предложение |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "гарнер" | "соберет" | «Надеюсь, ваш ответ наберет больше голосов, чем мой, потому что мой некачественный» |

---

## Определение *x проще, чем y*

> Для любых двух натуральных строк ***p1*** и ***p2***
>
> > натуральная строка ***p1*** проще, чем натуральная строка ***p2***
> >
> > > тогда и только тогда, когда
> > > оба из следующих (1 и 2):
> > >
> > > > (1) Для любого человеческого ***h***,
> > > >
> > > > > если
> > > > >
> > > > > > человек ***h*** знает значение естественной строки ***p1***
> > > > >
> > > > > тогда
> > > > >
> > > > > > человек ***h*** знает значение естественной строки ***p2***
> > >
> > > (2) на земле есть хотя бы один ребенок ***k*** такой, что:
> > >
> > > > пацан ***k*** знает, что означает способ-что-то сказать ***p1***
> > > >
> > > > > и
> > > >
> > > > пацан ***k*** не знает, что такое способ сказать что-то ***p2***

---

Например, может быть, у нас есть

(не стесняйтесь редактировать это)

> Фраза "*получить плюсы*" проще фразы "*собрать плюсы*"

---

> Для любого человека ***р***,
>
> > > если
> > >
> > > > ***p*** знает значение фразы "набирать плюсы"
> > > > тогда
> > > > ***p*** знает значение фразы "получить плюсы"
> >
> > и
> >
> > > > По крайней мере, один ребенок на земле знает фразу "получить плюсы", но не понимает фразу "набрать плюсы".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i guess that thay use the word следует or следовательно or the sign =>

Answer (score 2):

> если
> человек h знает значение естественной строки p1
> тогда
> человек h знает значение естественной строки p2

Связь между утверждениями, которая показана в этом примере, мы называем "[импликация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)". (Если я правильно понял, о чём был вопрос.)